# Where to download WindowsAzureSDK 1.8

Tags: azure, download, sdk, azure-cloud-services

I found Windows Azure SDK 2.0 but my old project has used Windows Azure SDK 1.8
so I need the same version to fix old project changes.

I have tried to upgrade using Windows Azure SDK 2.0 but it giving

Error   106 Role: '', setting 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Connect.EnableDomainJoin' in all service configurations could not be found in the service definition.   C:\Users\Hardik.Mehta\source\repos\Live\MFITD\\_Solution\_Role\ServiceDefinition.csdef

Comment: Have you referenced to [Azure SDK for .NET](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/archive-net-downloads/)?

Comment: @TomSun probably yes since his error is related to the old Cloud Services

Answer (score 0):

You can download all archived Azure SDKs for .NET [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/archive-net-downloads/). The Azure SDK Version 1.8 is from October 2012 and is **retired**.

You should **upgrade your SDK** since your Cloud Service will not be covered under the Azure Cloud Services SLA also it will not be covered under the support contract as well.
([Source](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/18486/lifecycle-faq-azure))

Comment: the [Link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/archive-net-downloads/) you have given is not of use, it has only version changes for 1.8 to 2.0 but no downloadable SDK for version 1.8